# How can I send JSON data to Logstash

Tags: java, http, post, elasticsearch, logstash

I know there is a Logstash `http` input plugin.
I am wondering if it is possible to send JSON message to Logstash using Java.

I do something like this:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("host_name:port/index_name/type_name");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"message\": {\"fieldName\":\"value\"}}");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

but data is not sent to Logstash.

Could anybody recommend the correct way to do that?

Comment: Any reason why it would not be possible? I think it definitely would :)

Comment: @yogidilip Could you recommend a tutorial for beginners explaining how to do that?